# Converting a column of UK dates to text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My system is in a UK locale (windows 7, office professional Plus 2013).

I have some columns of dates, stored as dates in the Uk format (dd/mm/yyyy) and I need to convert them to text in the same format.  The problem i'm having is it seems that every VBA function defaults to spitting out US format dates when converting to text.

I've tried using the range.TextToColumns function and example code is below (mostly macro recorder based - oddly text to columns works fine in excel, but the recorded code gives US dates... bizarre)

```
Sub ColumnToText(rngColumn As Range)
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Takes a column, coverts it to text
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------

rngColumn.TextToColumns _
    Destination:=rngColumn.Range("A1"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
    Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, _
    Space:=False, _
    Other:=False, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

There are plenty of ways I could do this by looping through the cells, but i'm aiming for an efficient solution that I can use in future as well as this case (i'm a little OCD about optimisation).

Ideally I'd like to be able to get the TextToColumns function to work in VBA the same way it does in Excel, but I realise that may not be possible.

Comment: Storing dates as text is rarely a good idea.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I don't have a choice, this is interface data for an application that wants the dates as text strings.

Comment: @Coder375 even 2 years on, this issue pertains. after trying all the below and more, i gave up. however, i share my solution with you. the data i had was from an email which was csv attachment. using VBA i was copying that data with dates into another workook and it was then that the date formats would mess up and turn to mm/dd/yyyy. I ended up just copying the data in the csv, and pasting it into a blank workbook and saving as XLSX. for some reason unbeknownst to me, this has fixed the issue. copying from an xlsx into the destination workbook was handled perfectly by VBA, but not for a csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With dates, if your OS (Windows) is in English-US you can use  r.Value = t

```
Set r = Range("a1:a9")
t = r.Value
r.NumberFormat = "@"
r.Value = t
```

Otherwise if you do not want the dates to be converted to the US date format, you must use  r.FormulaLocal = t

```
Set r = Range("a1:a9")
t = r.Value
r.NumberFormat = "@"
r.FormulaLocal = t
```

When a data is sent from vba to a cell, an internal type conversion function is called if required, that is if the data type is different from the numberformat property.
This internal type conversion function recognizes only the international date format (yyyy / mm / dd) and US dates formats (eg. mm / dd / yyyy)

You can use cell.FormulaLocal = data in place of cell.Value = data to avoid this function to be called.

Comment: Works perfectly, also I appreciate the explaination.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the whole column at once.

```
Sub foo()
[A:A].NumberFormat = "@"
[A:A] = [IF(A:A<>"", TEXT(A:A,"dd/mm/yyyy"),"")]
End Sub
```