# VBA changes date format upon copying from CVS file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a csv file which essentially has a column with dates formatted under the australian date format:

```
4/10/2016
15/03/2017
```

However, upon copying and pasting it to another workbook using the following code:

```
srcBook.Sheets(tabf).Range("B1:AD10000").Copy
Workbooks(thisworkbook).Activate
Sheets("raw Data").Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

for some entries, months/dates get swapped to the american format and become

```
10/04/2016
15/03/2017
```

I'm in the australian windows locale. Is it possible to fix this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: First, you can replace your 4 lines in your code with 1 : `srcBook.Sheets(tabf).Range("B1:AD10000").Copy Destination:= Workbooks(thisworkbook).Sheets("raw Data").Range("A2")` - there is no to `Activate` and `Select` in order to Copy>>Paste between workbooks. Regarding your date format, you can re-format it after the Paste with vba by using `Range("A2") = Format(Range("A2"), "dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: The second point won't help because only a single column has dates in it, the rest of values are integers which I would not want to cast to date in bulk.

Comment: Ok, so which column has the dates values in it from the original workbook?

Comment: may be a hint - what about restructuring this code to paste values only. And then I can pre-format the cells as either Text or the right date format. How would the code you are suggesting loook like to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: column 3 has dates

Comment: so when you paste it will be column 2 (B) ? or in the original it was column D, and after paste it's column C?

Comment: Yep, you are right

Comment: after the paste it's column C ?

Comment: It's column C, I am also thinking that this has something to do with the csv file format.

Comment: see if my answer below works for you as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
' copy >> paste in 1 line
srcBook.Sheets(tabf).Range("B1:AD10000").Copy Destination:= _
Workbooks(thisworkbook).Sheets("raw Data").Range("A2")

' convert column C to date format of "dd/mm/yyyy"
Workbooks(thisworkbook).Sheets("raw Data").Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

**Edit 1**:

```
' try copy >> paste special
srcBook.Sheets(tabf).Range("B1:AD10000").Copy
Workbooks(ThisWorkbook).Sheets("raw Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Comment: Not sure I see how the second point makes any difference? We are formatting this as to *appear* to reverse its month and date, it does not change the value of the date which remains reversed as described in the OP.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand the values were reversed, are they reversed in `Sheets(tabf)` before pasting them ?

Comment: yeah, it's a strange behaviour, Yes the original date in CSV is 4 Oct (appearing correctly as 4/10 under the australian format). When it's copied it becomes 10 Apr and appearing as 10/4. In both source and destination the formatting is australian, but somehow the value is interpreted as american on the way

Comment: Yeah, strange but it's the same problem, it seems as if the conversion happens at the copying stage, not pasting.

Comment: ok, i have some progress - if i save the CSV to xlsm first and then do what you are suggesting this works. I would really need to avoid an extra saving step as this is a runtime critical model.

Comment: not sure, but there are some issues and data format loss when converting from `.xlsx/m` to `.csv` and vice versa

Comment: Explanation and a solution to your Month/Day inversion here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310317/converting-a-column-of-uk-dates-to-text-in-vba/40314334#40314334

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this problem is always Open and Save CSV files with the **Local** attribute set to **True**

When you open a CSV file, you do it like this:

```
Workbooks.Open "path & filename.csv", Local:=True
```

and when you save it, you do this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="path & filename.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
```

Always adding the **, Local:=True**  at the end.

Comment: This is an elegant solution for the problem without fiddling with the cell formatting. Of course the user has to ensure that the file is only going to be used in the same region.

Comment: Vow an excellent solution.. is their any other option to just inform excel to read dates in given specific format instead of either region based or even automatic ?

Comment: If it can just read CSV as per configured format, then we can make it region independent also, if any such options know.. kindly let us know..

Answer (score 1):

I found that pasting a tab delimited dd/mm/yy string using CTRL-V does not swap the day-month but doing it using VBA does. I have just discovered that if you start with a yyyy-mm-dd string it does not swap day-month. My makro formats the cells before it pastes and that works too.

Comment: This method worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can format ranges with .NumberFormat using VBA.

```
srcBook.Sheets(tabf).Range("B1:AD10000").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

It seems strange that it would only change the date for some entries. Maybe the destination sheet has different formatting applied to different cells. If this is the case, select the cells or columns in the destination sheet, and format them to the correct date format within excel.